# Windows 8 locking files

Tags: windows-8, security

I have my UAC settings dialed down to 0 (lowest setting), but when I uninstall a program it wants to delete some profile data stored in my user directory.  Win8 denies access to the installer trying to delete files from this directory.  I am logged in as an Administrator and the c:\Users directory allows all access to everything in this folder.  How can I dumb down the security on Win8 so it doesn't try to protect stuff even though I am an admin?

Comment: Take ownership of files and folders you want to delete. And then, set the desired permissions..

Comment: lowest UAC slider setting doesn't disable UAC in Windows 8.